# Run android avd from command line

Tags: android-studio, cmd

Using windows 7 32bit, how can I run the avd from the command line?

I have my user and system variable, pointing to AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

When I try and use android avd, I get not recognised.

I have installed, Android SDK build tools v23.0.1

Any ideas?

Comment: You should always show the exact command and error message as text in the body of the question. Yes, always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by entering this command:

```
AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator -avd EMULATOR_NAME
```